# Write matrix and array operation inline

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, inline

I have two matrix and i sort after the first row of one of these and then sorting the other the same way:

```
[arrayYSorted, arrayYIndex] = sort(matrixA(:,1));
arrayX = matrixB(:,1);
arrayXSorted = arrayX(arrayYIndex);
```

I would like to write line 2 and 3 in one line but i can't figure out how to do the 'array from matrix' inline.

I did think of something like:

```
arrayXSorted = matrixB(:,1)(arrayYIndex);
```

or

```
arrayXSorted = (matrixB(:,1))(arrayYIndex);
```

but both isn't valid.

How to do this inline?

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, perfect! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the following, you can get the specified rows in column 1.

```
arrayXSorted = matrixB(arrayYIndex,1)
```